# How to trigger a request before sending another request using POSTMAN

Tags: api, rest, postman

I have two requests (Lets call them R1 and R2). I am able to trigger them individually from POSTMAN. But my requirement is, when R2 is triggered, automatically R1 should be triggered first and then R2 should be fired.

Please help me achieve this.

P.S: I Googled about this problem and no where it is mentioned about how to trigger another request from pre-request script. All they are saying is you can run some code in pre-request script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pm.sendRequest`](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/postman-sandbox-api-reference/#sending-requests-from-scripts) to send a request from a Pre-request or Test script.

Pre-request script

```
pm.sendRequest({
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',
    method: 'GET'    
}, function (err, res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

It will send *jsonplaceholder.typicode.com* request first and then actual request. You can use your request instead.

Comment: Where can I provide my request in the above code?

Comment: @MaruthiSrinivas, provide url in place of `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1`, method type and data (if it's POST request)

Comment: @MaruthiSrinivas this one and my answer are same . THe difference is that , in my answer instead of giving everything manually you are copying all this details from from r1 .

Comment: I personally use this approach to isolate one request from another, which helps me while test all apis in one go using newman.

Answer (score 6):

### in test script of R1 use

```
pm.environment.set("R1",pm.request)
```

### And in pre-request of R2

```
pm.sendRequest(pm.environment.get("R1"))
```

## Now when ever you send R2 , R1 will be send

Comment: Will this work if both R1 and R2 has different URL's??

Comment: yes the environment variable r1 will have all the details of r1 including url

Comment: you can verify this by going to postman console and checking the request was send or not

Comment: Tried the above solution and saw environment variable R1 is empty. Do I need to run R1 for the first time?

Comment: yes first run R1 to set the value for R1 its a one time operation

Comment: Yah got it. But my requirement is a bit complex. The request of R1 is some what dynamic. When I trigger R1 dynamic request will be prepared and then fired. The response of R1 is then feeded to R2 and then R2 should be triggered. The above solution you suggested will work only if my R1 request is static. Is there any other way I can achieve this?

Comment: what you mean by R1 not static the response or the request itself

Comment: Lets say R1 is a request that is creating new users. So every time R1 request will be dynamic like new first name and last name.

Comment: you can modify that in  pm.environment.get("R1") just print that you can see there are different properties modify as you want

Comment: Saving requests does not really work when you have a lot of headers/url/body params that need to be set on the first call and also need to run Tests from the chained requests. I my case I have 3 requests that do a lot of things during the call and inside their Test section to set the needed parameters for the next call. Each call depends on what parameters are fetched on the previous call. It seems like Postman simply cannot solve this issue and the only way around is to write thousands of lines of code inside the Test section of the first request in the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to run collection and not trigger R2 manually, then you can get help from how collection executes requests :

- Collection runs requests in order in which they appear in Postman. So you can control the order by arranging them appropriately within collection
- If collection has folders, then collection executes requests in folder first before executing requests at collection level. Again, you can arrange your requests in folders as you want them to be executed.

Reference : [controlling request flow](https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/building-workflows/#:%7E:text=When%20you%20start%20a%20collection,setNextRequest()%20.)

Answer (score 0):

Finally this is the solution I got.

```
pm.environment.set('access_token', 'eyJraWQiOi6XVYuL...');

pm.sendRequest({
    url: 'https://www.google.com/hello',
    method: 'POST',
    header: {
        'Content-Type': "application/json",
        'accept': "application/json",
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + pm.environment.get("access_token")
      },    
    body: {
        mode: 'raw',
        raw: JSON.stringify({ 
             key1: "value2",
             key2: "value1"
            })
    }
}, function (err, res) {
    console.log(res);
    const POSTResponse = res.json();
});
```